# How to target a specific TypeScript version?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing, typescript1.9

I've update my Angular 2 project to `RC1` and the router to `v3 alpha3`. I'm getting such errors:

```
node_modules/@angular/router/directives/router_outlet.d.ts(10,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
```

The error seem to be a [TypeScript version issue](https://github.com/angular/vladivostok/issues/39). I seem to be need to use TypeScript `1.9.0-dev.20160409` version or higher. I've added `"typescript": "^1.9.0-dev.20160409"` to `devDependencies` but didn't helped, I'm still getting same errors. What else should I do?

Comment: Where are you getting these errors? While compiling with `tsc` or in your IDE?

Comment: This is while compiling in VS.NET 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to upgrade your VS.NET to a specific version: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Nightly-drops#visual-studio-2013-and-2015

When you reopen the project VS.NET will ask that if you want to upgrade the project's TypeScript version. If you say yes it will update the `TypeScriptToolsVersion` value in the csproj file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that the latest TypeScript compiler version for Visual Studio 2015 is 1.8.6. In your project file you can set the node `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>` to 1.9. To use version 1.9 just download it and place it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.9\tsc.exe`.